# Added button successfully by using .innerHTML but can't access the button using its class name

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```
    function displaMatches (matches) {
  var searchText = document.querySelector('.search').value;
  var menu = document.querySelector('.menu')
  matches.forEach(match => {
    menu.innerHTML += `<li><button class="suggestion">${match}</button></li>`
  });

  var suggestions = document.querySelectorAll('.suggestion');
  suggestions.forEach(suggestion => {
    suggestion.addEventListener('click', () => {
      document.querySelector('.search').value = suggestion.textContent;
    });
  });
}
var search = document.querySelector('.search')

search.addEventListener('change', () => {
  var searchText = document.querySelector('.search').value
  autocomplete();
});

search.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
  var searchText = document.querySelector('.search').value
  autocomplete();
});

function autocomplete () {
  var searchText = document.querySelector('.search').value

  fetch(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.yelp.com/v3/autocomplete?&text=${searchText}&latitude=37.3351534&longitude=-122.0352478`, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Authorization": `Bearer ${access_token}`,
    }
  }).then((res) => {
    return res.json();
  }).then((data) => {
    var allData = [];
    allData.push(data);
    console.log(allData);
    let businesses = allData[0].businesses
    let categories = allData[0].categories
    let terms = allData[0].terms

    let matches = [];

    businesses.forEach(business => {
      matches.push(business.name);
    });

    categories.forEach(category => {
      matches.push(category.title);
    });

    terms.forEach(term => {
      matches.push(term.text);
    });
    displaMatches(matches);
  });
}
```

I can see buttons being added successfully to the menu on the page. However, when I tried to access a button using the class name "suggestion", what I got is null. What did I do wrong?

I changed my codes and the displayMatches function is now working fine. However, after I added the suggestion to the search box, the search button no longer works. If I disable the suggestion function, and type my own words into the search box, I can search anything with no problem. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Is the missing `=` in `<button class"suggestion">` a copy/paste error or is actual what it says in your code?

Comment: when using innerHTML read/write parser, be ware that buttons are *controls*.

Comment: yeah thanks. My bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this helps. I re-wrote the function

```js
function displaMatches (matches) {

   var menu = document.querySelector('.menu')

   matches.forEach(match => {
    //Create/add objects in javascript
    $li = document.createElement('li');
    $btn = document.createElement('button');
    $btn.className = 'suggestion';
    $btn.append(match);
    $li.appendChild($btn)
    menu.appendChild($li);
   });

   var suggestion = document.querySelectorAll('.suggestion')//this should return array of buttons with the defined classname

   console.log('ppp', suggestion[0]);

 suggestion.forEach(match => {
  match.onclick = () => {
   console.log(match.textContent)
   searchText = match.textContent;
  };
 })

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The way you create new html elements is very cool. I changed my codes accordingly and the function is now working fine. I am able to select a suggestion and add it into the search box. However, after I added the suggestion, the search button no longer works. If I disable the suggestion function, and type my own words into the search box, I can search anything with no problem. Do you know why?

Comment: var search = document.querySelector('.search')

search.addEventListener('change', () => {
  var searchText = document.querySelector('.search').value
  autocomplete();
})

search.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
  var searchText = document.querySelector('.search').value
  autocomplete();
})

Comment: With `querySelector`, consider id not class ie `querySelector('#search')` is ideal

Comment: #keepYourCodeClean ...
`var search = document.querySelector('#search');

search.addEventListener('change', () => { 
 var searchText = search.value autocomplete(); 
}) 

search.addEventListener('keyup', () => { 
 var searchText = search.value autocomplete(); 
}) `

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be missing an = sign. Should be:

`` menu.innerHTML += `<li><button class="suggestion">${match}</button></li>` ``

Also, keep in mind that if you to add an event listener to *every* `.suggestion` instead of just the first one, you need to use `var suggestion = document.querySelectorAll('.suggestion')`

Comment: Should probably use a comment to find out if the missing `=` is in the real code or just a copying error.

Comment: Good point. Didn’t consider that, as the rest of the code appeared correct, I jumped to straight to asuming it was “just” a typo.

Comment: If it's just a typo, don't bother posting an answer. Flag it for closing.

Comment: Roger that. I’ll do that in the future then

Answer (score 0):

There was a lot of errors, but here is something that works. Sorry, in old plain js.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="menu">
</ul>
<div id="searchtext">
</div>

<script>
    function displaMatches (matches) {

        var menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
        var item = function(match) {
            return '<li><button class="suggestion">' + match + '</button></li>';
        };

        var menuItems = [];

        for(var i=0;i<matches.length;i++){
            var m = matches[i];
            menuItems.push(item(m));
        }

        menu.innerHTML = menuItems.join('');

    }


   window.onload =  function() {
        var matches = [ 'red', 'blue', 'red' ];
        displaMatches(matches);

       setTimeout(function() {
           var suggestions = document.querySelectorAll('.suggestion');
           for (var i = 0; i < suggestions.length; i++) {
               suggestions[i].onclick = function () {
                   document.getElementById('searchtext').innerText += this.innerText;
               };
            }

       }, 1000);
    };
</script>

</body>
</html>
```